# Split a table in Word without losing row title

Tags: microsoft-word

Word has the feature to repeat title row of a table when a table is so long that it spans a bunch of pages.

I need to categorize my data into several pages, and I did that by splitting the table and insert page split to put them all in a page of itself. So now I got several page of data, but only the first page has title row.

Is there anyway else to do this beside manually adding the title row to all the other pages?

Original data:

```
 _________________
|  Cat.   Data    |
|   1      *      |
|   1      *      |
|   1      *      |
|   1      *      |
|   1      *      |
|   1      *      |
|   2      *      |
|   2      *      |
|   2      *      |
|   2      *      |
|   3      *      |
|___3______*______|
```

And then turn it into:

```
 _________________
|  Cat.   Data    |
|   1      *      |
|   1      *      |
|   1      *      |
|   1      *      |
|   1      *      |
|___1______*______|

Next page
 _________________
|  Cat.   Data    |
|   2      *      |
|   2      *      |
|   2      *      |
|___2______*______|

Next Page
 _________________
|  Cat.   Data    |
|   3      *      |
|___3______*______|
```

Comment: I know this is over five years old, but it’s unanswered and it just got bumped.  I don’t understand the question clearly.  Are you saying that you want to have a multi-page table (or what appears to be a multi-page table), but you want to force page breaks at specific rows (e.g., so the lions and the tigers aren’t on the same page as the bears),  rather than *just* allowing Word to insert an automatic page break every 50 rows (i.e., every nine inches)?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Or are you saying that you want to have several identically formatted tables in immediate succession (with each one beginning on a new page)?  Part of my question is: do you want to put non-tabular text between the categories?  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete (but also feel free to @-ping me in a comment).

Answer (score 4):

I'm posting a revised summary of the info referenced in detroit blackgirlmagic's response because I believe it perfectly answer's the OP's question, which is the same one I had.

Don't insert a manual page break in the table to force a row to a new page. Instead, use this formatting approach:

- Put the insertion point at the beginning of the row that you want on the new page.
- From the Home Ribbon,

  - Choose Paragraph (click drop-down icon in bottom right corner to bring up the Paragraph dialog box)
  - Choose the Line and Page Breaks tab
  - Select the "Page Break Before" check box (make sure it is checked).
- Click on OK.

[image]

Now the row will always start at the beginning of a new page, your table is not "broken" into two parts, and your desired rows will still repeat at the top of each page.

Comment: This did not work for me - however using keep with next for all lines then removing the KEEP WITH NEXT on the previous set of text did

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting the table, put the cursor into the table header and go to Table Tools>Layout and click Repeat Header Rows.

To categorize items in the way you specified, insert a page break in the row where you want the table to split (while having the above option enabled).

Comment: The OP stated "I need to categorize my data into several pages, and I did that by splitting the table and insert page split to put them all in a page of itself". Is there a way to include categorizing the data with this solution?

Comment: I know that, but that only work when "a table is so long that it spans a bunch of pages" as stated in my question.

Comment: Try inserting a page break in the table, instead of splitting the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the table on a **specific** row, you can do the following manual approach:

- At the start of the row you want on the next page, make a page break.
  This will not automatically create headers on each page, so you will need to re-create them manually.
- Insert a new row above the top row of the new table
- copy the header row of the first table
- overwrite the new top row of the second table you created with the header

This applies only when you want to split the tables on a **specific** row; I don't know of any way to make word do this automatically.

But **if you don't care** which row ends up onto a new page, then the "repeat as header row" option works.

Answer (score -1):

there's a new answer here that includes using the paragraph format section. super easy and way better than manual.

https://word.tips.net/T003504_Table_Header_Rows_after_a_Manual_Page_Break.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Link-only answers are generally discouraged here because the website linked to could disappear, making the answer worthless. Please [edit] your answer to post the relevant text from the link.